# How to save a sequence as a plain text file?

Tags: save

I would like to be able to generate data files like the ones provided with NIST SP 800-22 (binary expansions of irrational constants), which contain data akin to

```
1010011111001
```

According to the documentation the following Mathematica code is used to generate the data:

```
BinExp[num_,d_] := Module[{n,L},
                     If[d > $MaxPrecision, $MaxPrecision = d];
                        n = N[num,d];
                        L = First[RealDigits[n,2]]
                     ];

SE = BinExp[E,302500];
Save["data.e",{SE}];
```

However, when I run said code I get a file that begins with

```
SE = {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, ...
```

What can I do to make the saved file like th first example of just the 1s and 0s?

Comment: It is customary to stay responsive to comments as it is to provide feedback for the answers posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works. But may be there is better way

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
binExp[num_, d_] := 
  Module[{n, L}, If[d > $MaxPrecision, $MaxPrecision = d];
   n = N[num, d];
   L = First[RealDigits[n, 2]]];

SE = binExp[E, 302500]

Export["data.txt", StringJoin[ToString[#] & /@ SE]];
```

Screen shot of the file (the line is very long, over 1 million digits) this the start of it:

[image]

**Update**

Another option instead of explicitly converting the output to string is to use [Character8](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Character8.html) for format thanks to  suggestion by Ben Izd below.

```
 Export["data.txt", SE, "Character8"]
```

Both methods give the same exact output file.

Comment: I believe that this is a solution!

Comment: Appreciate the answer. It could be even more straightforward with ["Character8"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Character8.html) format.

Comment: @BenIzd thanks, updated answer with your suggestion.

Comment: You can use the `Export`'s third argument to specify the format to make it even better ;)

Comment: @BenIzd Yes, this is even better, I did not know about "character8", that is useful format to know.

Answer (score 2):

```
BinExp[num_, d_] := IntegerString[Round[2^d num], 2]
SE = BinExp[E, 302500];
Export["data.txt", SE]
```

Maybe use `Floor` instead of `Round`, depending on what you need for the last digit.